# What does Python's dir() function stand for?

Tags: python

I know that the dir() function gives you back either the names defined in the current scope or the names defined in an object. But why is it called dir()? Is it some mysterious acronyms like LISP's CAR and CDR?

Comment: Ah so this is a duplicate. I'm gonna close this question then. Thanks.

Comment: @Y.HWong Close it! Man!

Comment: I left a dupe vote. I think you can accept the dupe vote and close the question yourself now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It gives you an alphabetical listing of valid names (attributes) in the scope (object).  This is pretty much the meaning of the word *directory* in english.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably just an analogy to directory listing. `list()` is used for creating a lists, so dir() is used for listing elements object which has a similar tree-like structure to file system.

Just a guess.

Comment: Did I just ask a stupid question? Is it really simple like this?

Comment: kinda.. but maybe english is not your first language?

Comment: @wim: You are right. English is not my first language. I see you have over 2000 reputation. You can edit my answer. :-)

Comment: @Y.HWong: It's human nature to be curious. I looked at the python source code and there is no comments except for docstring for the `dir()`. I'm sure if there would be some magic about it, it will be described there. It wasn't, so I guess it's that simple.

Comment: @wim English is not my first language, but I think I've been in the states long enough to be my second :) I guess I just can't wrap my head around having a "directory" of any "object". What does a directory of a class mean? I got some mind blockage there.

Comment: I think the MS-DOS analogy is a red herring.  The directory of a class would just be a common-sense usage of the meaning of directory in plain english, like I wrote in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it's a reference to the [`DIR`](http://www.csulb.edu/~murdock/dir.html) command of MSDOS. DIR does directory listings, like the Unix command `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

I know that without arguments, it returns a list of names in the current local scope. For example:

```
>>>z = 3
>>>def f1():
...    x = 1
...    y = 2
...    print dir()
...
>>>f1()
['x','y']
>>>print dir()
['z',something else]
```

With arguments, it returns a sorted dictionary keys of all the attributes of that object. for example:

```
>>>import sys
>>>dir(sys)
[a bunch of attributes of sys]
```